# Spring @GetMapping in @Controller not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using the Spring framework. I have tried a little bit using Rest and using View. I have a problem in routing the application.

If I use `@RestController` in my controller, it works well. But in this case I want to user view so I use `@Controller`. But when I use `@Controller` it always returns an error "not found".

This is my code:

```
@RestController
public class LombaController {

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String get(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

That code works when I request to `http://localhost:8080/get`. But it returns a string "index" instead of my view template. I get a solution to using `@Controller` instead of `@RestController` to render the view. But it always returns an error "not found". This is my code when I use `@Controller`:

```
@Controller
public class LombaController {

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String get(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And this is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.crudcoba</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-crud-coba</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-crud-coba</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to specify *the exact error* instead of just telling us it's a "not found"; you're probably getting a useful error report on the server console. Most likely, you don't have a template named `index.html` in the expected location, and you haven't shown us one.

Comment: Hey, thank for your answer. I got the problem in my view template location

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

instead of

```
@GetMapping("/get")
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, the main problem is from my resources location

Comment: How does it help?

Comment: I think the problem is in my template directory, not in GetMapping or RequestMapping annotation

Answer (score 2):

`@RestController` adds `@RequestBody` annotation to your methods, which will indeed return a `String` "index".

If you want to use your template file, put it in `/src/main/resources/templates/index.html` and change your `@RestController` to `@Controller`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The problem is the resources folder. My resource folder is under */src/main/*, this is spring default config when I download from official page and didn't work in my case. So I have move it into */src/main/java* folder, and it work smoothly..

Comment: @AdiSparta That isn't the correct location and shouldn't resolve the issue. The templates should be in `src/main/resources/templates/{index.html}`.

Comment: @chrylis that was a "shortcut", I will edit my answer to include `src/main` part to avoid any confusion

Comment: @chrylis I didn't no what going on here, but now it work when I run using template from `src/main/resources/templates/{index.html}` . May be the cache i think...

Comment: @AdiSparta There are two steps that might cause trouble. Make sure to disable the Thymeleaf cache (see `application.properties`; your IDE will probably autocomplete entries for you) and to make sure your IDE copies changes in the source HTML to the runtime classpath (Eclipse will do this automatically, IntelliJ might need a project refresh).

Comment: @chrylis yeah, I think the cache of `application.properties` too.. Because I have move the resources file that contains `application.properties` and it return error on start server. I move it back and the view run smoothly.. Thanks buddy